# Check if a folder is writable

Tags: c, file-io, cross-platform

I'm writing an simple file server using sockets for an assignment. Before I start accepting connections I need to check that the server can write to the requested directory it serves from.

One simple way of doing this would simply be to try create a file and then delete it straight afterwards and error if that failed. But what if the file already exists? My program crashes or gets closed in-between? Along with the fact it seems a bit messy and isn't elegant.

Strictly speaking the code only needs to work for an Ubuntu system the markers test it on. So I could do a stat() command, get the current uid and gid and check the permissions manually against the file status. But I'd rather do this in a portable fashion and this is laborous..

Is there a simple `C` standard way of doing this?

Comment: You know about access() ?

Comment: No i did not. It looks like a access() call with the path of the directory and the how argument of W_OK may work. I can then check to see if it returns 0. I'll test it out now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `access` from `<uninstd.h>`.  I don't know if it's part of the standard, but it is more convenient than `stat`, I would say.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int result = access("/root/", W_OK);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Can W_OK" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Can't W_OK: " << result << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Posted my C version below also.

Comment: access checks with real UID instead of effective UID. You need to use faccessat with AT_EACCESS flag to check the  accessibility with effective user and group IDs.

Comment: @Callum Thanks for adding a C version to the C question.  Dunno what this guy was thinking.  Probably trying to make stackoverflow crappier.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it works, cheers.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_folder_writable(char* str) {
    if(access(str, W_OK) == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome to see a C response to a C question!